# How can I extract the indices from a pandas.DataFrame where values intersect another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have two pandas dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

friends = pd.dataframe({
    'name' : ['Alice', 'Jim', 'Edward'],
})

everyone = pd.dataframe({
    'name' : ['Edward', 'Conrad', 'Lucy', 'Jim', 'Frank', 'Alice', 'Sam']
})
```

I can get a list of my friends, in the 'everyone' order, with indices.

```
everyone.loc[everyone['name'].isin(friends['name'])]
```

I can get a boolean mask of where my friends are in 'everyone'.

```
everyone['name'].isin(friends['name'])
```

I even thought I was onto a clunky solution with the following, but it also re-ordered things.

```
everyone.reset_index().merge(friends, how='right', on='name').set_index('index')
```

But I can't figure out how to get their ordinal place in the 'everyone' dataframe. Ideally, the solution would add a lookup column to the friends dataframe that looks like below. Alice is the 5th entry in everyone; Jim is the 3rd; Edward the 0th. The order (matching my original friends' order) is obviously critical.

```
  name   everyone_id
0 Alice   5
1 Jim     3
2 Edward  0
```

I could probably write a slow lookup function and friends.apply() it, but assume pandas has a simpler function or argument I just can't find.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html)`with`swapped indices with values:

```
d = everyone['name'].to_dict()
d = {v:k for k, v in d.items()}

friends['everyone_id'] = friends['name'].map(d)
print (friends)
     name  everyone_id
0   Alice            5
1     Jim            3
2  Edward            0
```

Similar solution is [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series`:

```
s = pd.Series(everyone['name'].index, index=everyone['name'].values)
friends['everyone_id'] = friends['name'].map(s)
print (friends)

     name  everyone_id
0   Alice            5
1     Jim            3
2  Edward            0
```

Comment: Interesting. I never thought outside of pandas to use normal python language features like dictionaries. And map is very helpful. :-) Thank you @jezrael